# Cannot start Aurelia app without eval()

Tags: javascript, aurelia, systemjs

I have a working Aurelia SPA web app, but if I set in my web.config the Content-Security-Policy option like this

```
<add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none'; frame-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.core.windows.net; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com 'self';"></add>
```

I get this error on page load

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com".
```

I loaded the page now using the unbundled version and the error I get is

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://code.jquery.com".

Evaluating https://localhost/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0.js
Error loading https://localhost/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0.js
```

in the meantime I will investigate the SystemJS module loader further.

**UPDATE**

The error happens indeed in the SystemJS module loader, because in system.src.js it uses eval (plus a couple of 'new Function' definitions, but I don't come tho those lines of code.
My question would then be: is there no way to work around this other than switching off the Content-Security-Policy (or allowing 'unsafe-eval')?

Comment: what if you change `'self'` to `'unsafe-eval'` in *web.config*?

Comment: yes, if I do that (or don't specify any policy at all like I had until now) it would work, but I would like to have a more restrictive policy for security reasons.

Comment: Curious, where did you find the `eval` in the Aurelia code?

Comment: Aurelia does not use `eval`. I suspect it's the SystemJS module loader.

Comment: Thanx for the hints. After a bit more investigation I found it in the bluebird node module of aurelia-bundler, but I don't think it has to do with my problem. I will update my question with more details though. It is possible it has to do with the SystemJS module loader as Jeremy says.

Comment: Note that code loaders are one of the few totally legitimate cases for eval...

Comment: Another approach might be switching to Aurelia cli as that does not use systemjs

Comment: I will try that thanx zewa666

Answer (score 2):

Aurelia fully supports Content Security Policy.  If you are using SystemJS, you need to do the following changes to your index.html, compared to the getting started sample found in the [Aurelia documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start):

Use the CSP compatible [production build](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md#csp-compatible-production) of SystemJS:

```
<script src="scripts/system-csp-production.js"></script>
```

Note that using the CSP version of SystemJS, you can *only run bundled* or it *will not work*.  You probably want to use the line above in production only.

Create a file bootstrap.js with the following contents:

```
System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
```

and replace the same, inlined call in index.html with the following line:

```
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

[Here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/54) is a relevant issue on the Aurelia project.

Comment: Very interesting to know. By now I have already switched to the AureliaCLI (which does not use SystemJS and also runs always bundled). This would have been an interesting approach. But it is good to know that there is also this possibility, thank you.

Comment: I have a CSP working in Aurelia without the need for unsafe directives - just need to include the hash values provided by Chrome for the injected inline styles used by aurelia e.g `content-security-policy:default-src 'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com ajax.googleapis.com accounts.google.com; style-src 'self' 'sha256-ATeSIcqM6UxTblzmyyICgZWZUpvkDFfJxeK3WjeUN90=' 'sha256-2CtcL7mgol0+aS4MUS6bARLtOylI9akJkKjFDqfDzhQ='; frame-ancestors 'none';`