# Aurelia with knockout secure binding

Tags: knockout.js, aurelia

Hi I have an Aurelia web app running with the [Aurelia CLI](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6).

Before, I used SystemJS as module loader, but since I want to enforce the Content-Security-Policy of my app in order not to allow 'unsafe-eval', I changed to the Aurelia CLI as suggested to me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237961/cannot-start-aurelia-app-without-eval).

My app is a former Durandal app which I am converting to Aurelia, therefore it uses Knockout extensively. I am using the aurelia-knockout plugin (as you can see in my main.js)

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()        
        .plugin('aurelia-knockout');

    return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

and I have installed both the knockout and the knockout-secure-binding npm packages and configured them in the aurelia.json file:

```
"dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          "aurelia-bootstrapper",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator",
          "aurelia-framework",
          "aurelia-history",
          "aurelia-history-browser",
          "aurelia-loader",
          "aurelia-loader-default",
          "aurelia-logging",
          "aurelia-logging-console",
          "aurelia-metadata",
          "aurelia-pal",
          "aurelia-pal-browser",
          "aurelia-path",
          "aurelia-polyfills",
          "aurelia-route-recognizer",
          "aurelia-router",
          "aurelia-task-queue",
          "aurelia-templating",
          "aurelia-templating-binding",
          {
            "name": "text",
            "path": "../scripts/lib/text"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-resources",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-resources"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-router",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-router"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-knockout",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-knockout/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-knockout"
          },
          {
            "name": "knockout",
            "path": "../node_modules/knockout/build/output",
            "main": "knockout-latest"
          },
          {
            "name": "knockout-secure-binding",
            "path": "../node_modules/knockout-secure-binding/dist",
            "main": "knockout-secure-binding.min"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-testing",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-testing",
            "env": "dev"
          }
        ]
```

I know I have to use the following code (as I did in my old Durandal app) to activate knockout secure bindings:

```
var options = {
        attribute: "data-bind",        // default "data-sbind"
        globals: window,               // default {}
        bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  // default ko.bindingHandlers
        noVirtualElements: false       // default true
    };
ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(options);
```

but I do not know how to use it in this new Aurelia app, or in general how to make the aurelia-knockout plugin use the secure binding version of knockout.
I have tried modifying my main.js file like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {        
    var options = {
        attribute: "data-bind",        // default "data-sbind"
        globals: window,               // default {}
        bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  // default ko.bindingHandlers
        noVirtualElements: false       // default true
    };
    ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(options);

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()        
        .plugin('aurelia-knockout');

    return aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

or even tweaking the aurelia-knockout.js file in the npm module, inserting the secure binding definition just before this line

```
ko.applyBindings(executionContext, this.element);
```

but, even if I got no build errors (I build using the "au build" command) none of the above worked.

**UPDATE**

I inserted the ko secure binding initialization code directly inside

```
node_modules\aurelia-knockout\dist\amd\aurelia-knockout-custom-attribute.js
```

and I added a reference to the secure binding module in the 1st line like so

```
define(['exports', 'aurelia-dependency-injection', 'aurelia-templating', 'knockout-secure-binding'], function (exports, _aureliaDependencyInjection, _aureliaTemplating, _knockoutSecureBinding) {
```

and now I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: ko.secureBindingsProvider is not a constructor
```

as if the secure binding module had not been found/loaded.

Anyway, I don't think that freaking around with the "built" version of a node_module is the ideal solution, I am just searching for a way to make it work. Still looking forward to better proposals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a working solution:

First, in aurelia.json file I define the "loader" property like that:

```
"loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "config": {
        "waitSeconds": 0,
        "paths": {
          "jquery": "../scripts/lib/cdn/jquery-3.1.0.min",
          "knockout": "../scripts/lib/knockout-3.4.0"          
        }
      },
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "extensions": [
            ".html",
            ".css"
          ],
          "stub": true
        }
      ]
    },
```

this way I have knockout defined "globally". The "bundles" property is so defined:

```
"bundles": [
      {
        "name": "app-bundle.js",        
        "source": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",          
          "scripts/lib/require.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          "aurelia-bootstrapper",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator",
          "aurelia-fetch-client",
          "aurelia-framework",
          "aurelia-history",
          "aurelia-history-browser",
          "aurelia-loader",
          "aurelia-loader-default",
          "aurelia-logging",
          "aurelia-logging-console",
          "aurelia-metadata",
          "aurelia-pal",
          "aurelia-pal-browser",
          "aurelia-path",
          "aurelia-polyfills",
          "aurelia-route-recognizer",
          "aurelia-router",
          "aurelia-task-queue",
          "aurelia-templating",
          "aurelia-templating-binding",
          {
            "name": "text",
            "path": "../scripts/lib/text"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-resources",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-resources"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-router",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-router"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-knockout",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-knockout/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-knockout"
          },          
          {
            "name": "aurelia-testing",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-testing",
            "env": "dev"
          },
          {
            "name": "icheck",
            "path": "../node_modules/icheck",
            "main": "icheck.min"
          },
          {
            "name": "filesaver.js",
            "path": "../node_modules/filesaver.js",
            "main": "FileSaver.min"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Now I load all the plugins I require inside the main.js before the app is started, and I add the corresponding plugins to the globak "ko" variable:

```
    export function configure(aurelia) {    
        aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()        
            .globalResources('views/panel_header.html')        
            .plugin('aurelia-knockout');

        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
        var prefix = '../';
        var scripts = [
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/breeze.debug",
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/knockout-secure-binding",
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/knockout.binding.handlers",
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/knockout.wrap",
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/knockout.dirtyFlag",
            prefix + "/scripts/lib/knockout-sortable.min"
        ];

        return aurelia.start().then(() => {
            require(scripts, function(breeze, secureBindingProvider, kbh, wrap, dirtyFlag, sortable) {
                require([
                    prefix + "/scripts/lib/breeze.savequeuing",
                ], function(savequeuing){
                    ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider({
    attribute: "data-bind",        // default "data-sbind"
    globals: window,               // default {}
    bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  // default ko.bindingHandlers
    noVirtualElements: false       // default true
});
                    ko.wrap = wrap;            
                    ko.dirtyFlag = dirtyFlag;
                    ko.sortable = sortable;
                    aurelia.setRoot();
                });             
            });                     
        });    
    }
```

Now, when the aurelia-knockout plugin performs the binding, it uses the "knockout-secure-binding" instance as I wish.